# Switch Case statement for Regex matching in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have a bunch of regexes and I try to see if they match with another string using this If statement:

```js
if (samplestring.match(regex1)) {
  console.log("regex1");
} else if (samplestring.match(regex2)) {
  console.log("regex2");
} else if (samplestring.match(regex3)) {
  console.log("regex3");
}
```

But as soon as I need to use more regexes this gets quite ugly so I want to use a switch case statement like this:

```js
switch(samplestring) {
  case samplestring.match(regex1): console.log("regex1");
  case samplestring.match(regex2): console.log("regex2");
  case samplestring.match(regex3): console.log("regex3");
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work like I did it in the example above.
Any Ideas on how it could work like that?

Comment: I think you skipped `break`.

Comment: Every case that comes after the one that was matched will be executed, unless the browser reads the `break` keyword.

Comment: i added the break keyword but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use a different check, not with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), that returns an array or `null` which is not usable with strict comparison like in a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

You may use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) and check with `true`:

```js
var regex1 = /a/,
    regex2 = /b/,
    regex3 = /c/,
    samplestring = 'b';

switch (true) {
    case regex1.test(samplestring):
        console.log("regex1");
        break;
    case regex2.test(samplestring):
        console.log("regex2");
        break;
    case regex3.test(samplestring):
        console.log("regex3");
        break;
}
```

Comment: this works but i read somewhere that this isnt a very clean method of doing a switch case statement, is this true?

Comment: it's a clean pattern beside that it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "not null":

```js
const regex1=/just$/;
    const regex2=/foo$/;
    const regex3=/bars$/;
    var samplestring="just enough foobars";
    switch(true){
      case !!samplestring.match(regex1): document.write("regex1 matched"); break; 
      case !!samplestring.match(regex2): document.write("regex2 matched"); break;
      case !!samplestring.match(regex3): document.write("regex3 matched"); break;
    }
```

Comment: I tried it in Typescript and got the error `Type 'boolean' is not comparable to type 'string'.ts(2678)`