# Implementing a navbar nested view in angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Am new to the angular js.
Am implementing a nested ui view but the problem is when checking the current state of a page it returns many objects such that i cant use $state.current to set the ng-show

I would like the navbar shown and hidden in some states.

I have tried

```
The main index.html page
<html>......
<body ng-app="myapp">
<nav ng-controller="headerCtrl" ng-show="shownav()" >
  //here is the navbar code..The shownav is defined on the headerCtrl

</nav>

<div ui-view>   </div>

//Angular js, controllers and services links


</body>
</html>
```

The app.js code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.controller('headerCtrl',function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.shownavbar = function(){
        var state = $state.current;
       if(state ==='login' ){
       return false;
       }else{
       return true;
   }         
}
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider){

 $stateProvider
.state('login', {
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/index/login/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
 })

.state('dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    templateUrl:'templates/layout/dashboard.html',
    abstract:true
})

.state('dash.call',{
    url: '/call',
    templateUrl: 'templates/index/calls/calls.html',
    controller: 'callCtrl'
})

 .state('dash.profile', {
 url: '/profile',
 templateUrl: 'templates/index/account/profile/profile.html',
 controller: 'profileCtrl'

 })


});
```

I would like the navbar hidden for some states like when a user is on the login state

At the headerctrl i have also tried

```
 $scope.shownavbar = function(){
        var state = $state.current;
        $log.info(state);

  }
```

This returns in the console:

```
angular.js:13708 Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
angular.js:13708 Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
angular.js:13708 Object {url: "/login", templateUrl:  "templates/index/login/login.html", controller: "loginCtrl", name: "login"}
angular.js:13708 Object {url: "/login", templateUrl: "templates/index/login/login.html", controller: "loginCtrl", name: "login"}
 angular.js:13708 Object {url: "/login", templateUrl: "templates/index/login/login.html", controller: "loginCtrl", name: "login"}
```

WHAT COULD BE THE PROBLEM

Comment: maybe you can use a `$rootScope` to save true or false, and in the path of `run()` use a function that see when the state is changing and hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think in two ways to solve this.

**First solution**
**EDITED**

inside your `run()` put a function to see when the state is changing and hide or show the navbar.

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.navbar = false;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (toState.name === 'login') {//toState variable see the state you're going 
            $rootScope.navbar = false;
        } else {
            $rootScope.navbar = true;
        }
    });
});
```

and change in your `ng-show="navbar"`

**Second solution**

the second solution i can think is you use multiple views.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: null,
                controller: null
            },
            'body': {
                templateUrl: "views/login.html",
                controller: 'LoginController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'navbar': {
                templateUrl: "views/navbar.html",
                controller: null
            },
            'body': {
                templateUrl: "views/inicio.html",
                controller: null
            }
        }
    });
```

and in your `html` views put something similar to this:

```
<div ui-view="navbar"></div>
<div ui-view="body"></div>
```

Comment: The first solution is the best but doesnt work... After trying console.log($state.current) in the   $rootScope.$on('stateChangeStart..... ) block it returns null but console.log($state) returns something...

Comment: i'm so sorry i've tested it and it have a fews changes, please see my update

Comment: Now it works thanks.. Could you also add on how to handle the check of state using switch statement instead of if(..) else...

Comment: you can use it as same as a numer, please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896626/switch-statement-for-string-matching-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the help