# JavaScript Switch Statement with String Includes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been looking for something where I could test if a variable has a certain word with switch statement:

**JavaScript**

```
var str = "We are VR Troopers";

switch (str) {
 case str.includes("are"):
   // do something;
   break;
  // no default
}
```

I have looked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and found nothing. Can you provide a link with your answers? That's a plus for my learning. Thanks.

I want to limit the use if too many `if`'s.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution if you don't want to use `if` is to use the `switch(true)` construct.

I'd also suggest to avoid `includes` when you have a constant argument to check as its support is quite poor today (neither IE nor Edge support it) and to favor a regular expression instead (use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) if your argument is variable).

See:

```
var str = "We are VR Troopers";

switch (true) {
 case /are/.test(str):
   // do something;
   break;
  // no default
}
```

You may improve it to test whether it's word, for example, or be case insensitive with expressions like `/\bare\b/` or `/are/i`.

Comment: is it a good practise to use regex inside switch case? Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2896642/6237235

Comment: @Iceman it's not a bad practice per se but it turns out there's usually a better solution, which I can't infer from the too limited question (in this specific case the obvious solution is a `if`).

Comment: The answer works but using `if` maybe too much to type.