# How to turn if statement that use classList.contains() as condition to switch statement?

Tags: javascript

How can I turn the following `if/else if` statement into `switch` statement?  Is it possible to do so?

```
if(event.target.classList.contains("follow-user")){
        sendFollowRequest(event.target, 'subscribedUsers');
      } else if(event.target.classList.contains("follow-hashtag")){
        sendFollowRequest(event.target, 'subscribedHashtags');
      } else if(event.target.classList.contains("follow-cat")){
        sendFollowRequest(event.target, 'subscribedCategories');
      }
```

Comment: switch is meant for an exact comparison. I would just clean up the code so it is not so copy paste happy.

Comment: There's no good way of doing that; it seems fine the way it is.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896642/5605822

Comment: Counter question: why? What is the benefit you expect from this?

Answer (score 0):

A switch is really for matching exact matches. There are some bad practices where you can use true in the switch for the match. If you are looking to clean up the code. You can easily use variables to pull out common stuff, still will be a lot of code.

```
var target = event.target 
var cList = target.classList
if(cList.contains("follow-user")){
  sendFollowRequest(target, 'subscribedUsers');
} else if(cList.contains("follow-hashtag")){
  sendFollowRequest(target, 'subscribedHashtags');
} else if(cList.contains("follow-cat")){
  sendFollowRequest(target, 'subscribedCategories');
}
```

Other option is using an object and loop

```js
var subscribedOptions = {
  'follow-user': 'subscribedUsers',
  'follow-hashtag': 'subscribedHashtags',
  'follow-cat': 'subscribedCategories',
}

function clicky(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  var cList = target.classList;
  
  Object.entries(subscribedOptions).forEach(function(req) {
    if (cList.contains(req[0])){
      sendFollowRequest(target, req[1]);
    }
  })

}

function sendFollowRequest(target, action) {
  console.log(target, action);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".bar").forEach(b => b.addEventListener("click", clicky))
```

```html
<button class="foo bar follow-hashtag">foo bar follow-hashtag</button>
<button class="foo bar follow-user">foo bar follow-user</button>
<button class="foo bar follow-cat">foo bar follow-cat</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
let follow = {"follow-user":"subscribedUsers", "follow-hashtag":"subscribedHashtags", "follow-cat":"subscribedCategories"}
Object.keys(follow).forEach(e=>{
      if(event.target.classList.contains(e)){
        sendFollowRequest(event.target, follow[e]);
      }
});
```