# Matching a URL via wildcard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, typescript, frontend

I have reviewed some similar posts but unfortunately I am unable to get this right...

I have a switch statement that is providing a MD file depending on the URL path. Each path has many subpaths, for example /notebook/users/id and I would like to always match based on /notebook. I have attempted a few regex patterns but I am unable to successfully add the wildcard:

```
switch (location.href) {
        case `${URLZ}/${/^notebook.*/}`:
            return <Markdown value={data.notebook} />;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you wanna check if the URL contains a `"/notebook"`?

Comment: That is exactly it! Please let me know if I am missing any further needed info

Comment: Looks like [the answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896626/switch-statement-for-string-matching-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you're sure no other URLs contain `'/notebook'` beside the ones that should return `<Markdown />` then refactor your switch statement to take `true` and do the check on your `case`s:

You can use [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if the `location.href` contains a `'/notebook'`

```js
switch (true) {
  case location.href.includes('notebook'):
    return <Markdown value={data.notebook} />;
```

Comment: That works perfect! Thank you for the insight!