# Switch case with pathname :id route React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, router

I don't find the way ton fix my issue. I want a specific state if the route is '/blablabla/:id'. I know how to find the simple route as '/blabla'. With a if statement is ok but i need to use switch case. Thanks for your help

```
 useEffect(() => {
    switch (location.pathname) {
      case '/':
        setTitle('My Board');
        break;
      case '/offers':
        setTitle('My Offer');
        break;
      case '/invoice':
        setTitle('Invoices');
        break;
      case location.pathname.match(/\d+$/): -- The route is /invoice/:id --> the id is a number 
        setTitle('Invoice Number ***');
        break;
      default:
        setTitle('My Board');
    }
  }, [location]);
```

Comment: so whats the issue? it doesn't trigger the case?

Comment: no i doesnt work. i cant match my regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement for string matching in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896626/switch-statement-for-string-matching-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex just checks for numbers but not the characters before it. This checks for **characters** followed by a **slash** and **numbers**.

```
^([a-z]+\/[0-9]+)
```

Comment: yes right but its strange it like if the regex doesnt match like this...

Comment: any error or something? maybe try hardcoding and see if it works. if not, then you're digging up the wrong hole :D

Comment: so i find the right way :
    switch (true) {
....
      case /\d+$/.test(location.pathname):



but how to regex a pathname like this : /account/sample-page because the - is a problem wiith regex ??