# How to write case in Switch else statement in javavscript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

//This is my Problem
Complete the getLetter(s) function in the editor. It has one parameter: a string, , consisting of lowercase English alphabetic letters (i.e., a through z). It must return A, B, C, or D depending on the following criteria:

```
If the first character in string  is in the set {aeiou}, then return A.
If the first character in string  is in the set {bcdfg}, then return B.
If the first character in string  is in the set {hjklm},, then return C.
If the first character in string  is in the set {npqrstvwxyz}, then return D.

I am trying to implement the above scenarion and to dthis I have written the following code. 

//Here is my code
    function getLetter(s) {
        let letter;
        // Write your code here
        
            switch (s) {
            case s.match(/[aeiou]/g).includes(s[0]):
            letter = 'A'
            break; 
            
            case s.match(/[bcdfg]/g).includes(s[0]):
            letter = 'B'
            break; 
        
            case s.match(/[hjklm]/g).includes(s[0]):
            letter = 'C';
            break; 
            
            case s.match(/[npqrstvwxyz]/g).includes(s[0]):
            letter = 'D';
            break; 
            default:
            console.log("hello")
        }
        return letter
    }

The code is showing error. Would any help me to figure it out? How can I implement the above task using switch statement.
```

Comment: So what is the code shown doing differently than expected? Any errors? What is your question? See [ask]

Comment: Is that answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896626/switch-statement-for-string-matching-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that much switch case, but maybe you can use parenthesis for the switch statement and if "s.match(/[aeiou]/g).includes(s[0])" return true or false
And you forgot ";" after the two first assignment

Answer (score 0):

the way you wrote the switch case may be partially correct in GoLang. but in Javascript, it is not possible to achieve this using Switch-Case statement.

Better try using if-else-if statement something like below

```
if(s.test(/^[aeiou]/)) {
    return 'A';
} else if(s.test(/^[bcdfg]/)) {
    return 'B'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: [Switch statement for string matching in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896626/switch-statement-for-string-matching-in-javascript). The issue is that match returns null, which breaks the switch statement.
Use

```
switch(s){
    case str.match(/^xyz/)?.input:
        //code
        break;
```

This stops the match from returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you're using this, you actually want to `switch (true)` and not `switch (s)`

i.e. when you have a `case y` in a `switch (x)`, the test being done is `x === y`; so you want to do `true === some.test()`

```js
const s = 'a';

switch (true) {
  case /a/.test(s):
    console.log('first match');
    break;
  case /b/.test(s):
    console.log('second match');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('no match');
    break;
}
```

Will log `first match` because

- `/a/.test('a')` is `true`
- and `true /* from switch */ === true /* from case test */`

---

Note that in most cases `switch` can also be written as `if..else if..else`.
Base your decision on which to use by which is the most readable (err on the side of `if` patterns)

The above example written as an `if` might look like this

```js
const s = 'a';

if (/a/.test(s)) {
  console.log('first match');
} else if (/b/.test(s)) {
  console.log('second match');
} else {
  console.log('no match');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. It saves my time.

Comment: That's a bad way of using `switch`.

Comment: @Andy think it is okay where it makes the code more readable. I've added the suggestion to use an `if`

Comment: `switch (true)` will never be more readable because that's not it was designed for.