# I have a script that deletes sheets and retains a list of sheets that I do not want to delete, but the list of tabs I want to retain changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a project in which I want to delete a set of sheets in order to clean up and start over. I have a script that does this, but I am also adding some backup sheets that I do not want to delete. In other words the **sheets not to delete** changes as I add these backup sheets.

```
function DeleteAllSheets() {
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  //for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) 
  sheets.forEach(function (item, i) {
    switch (sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
      case "roster":
      case "template":      
      case "Test":      
        break;
      default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  })
}
```

I  have another script that creates backups of the roster sheet from time to time and names the backups "**Backup Test (Date)**" *or* where the name of the back up sheet name always begins with 'Backup Test' but has a different date. Instead of having to go into the script to add these backups from being deleted, is there a way with the 'case' function to use some logic like "**contains Backup Test**" or "**begins with Backup Test**" to keep these from being deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
function myfunction() {
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  const xcl = ["roster", "template", "Test"]
  shts.forEach((sh, i) => {
    let nam = sh.getName()
    let idx = xcl.indexOf(nam);
    if (!~idx && !nam.includes("backup")) {
      ss.deleteSheet(sh);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way with the 'case' function to use some logic like 'contains Backup Test' or 'begins with Backup Test' to keep these from being deleted.

The function you're  looking for is [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
if(sheet.getName().includes("Backup Test"))
```

You can also use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) with [Regex.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Regexp/test):

```
if(/^(?:Backup Test.*|roster|template|Test)$/.test(sheet.getName())))
```

```
const deleteAllExcept = () => { 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => 
    /^(?:Backup Test.*|roster|template|Test)$/.test(sheet.getName()) && ss.deleteSheet(sheet))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do it is to have the names of the sheets to be saved in an array.

```
function deleteSheets() {
  const save = ["roster","templete","Test"]
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
      let name = sheet.getSheetName();
      if( save.indexOf(name) >= 0 ) return;
      if( name.indexOf("Backup Test") >= 0 ) return;
      ss.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

You can also use the [MATCH](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) with [REGEX](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) in your existing **SWITCH** statement script to check if there are any `sheet names` that contain the word "**backup**" / "**roster**" / "**Test**" / "**template**", as seen on this tweaked script:

### Tweaked Script

```
function DeleteAllSheets() {
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function (item, i) {
    switch (sheets[i].getSheetName()) {
      case ((sheets[i].getSheetName().match(/(?:backup|roster|test|template)/gi)) ? sheets[i].getSheetName() : undefined):     
        break;
      default:
        ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  })
}
```

This method was derived from this existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22099079).

### Demonstration

- Test `spreadsheet` **before** running the script

[image]

- Test `spreadsheet` **after** running the script

[image]

Comment: @TimWelch Feel free to respond if you have any follow up questions